# How can I call "delete row " event when i click on "edit" button in gridview? asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview I want that when I click on "edit" button in gridview then edit row values inserted in the controls which is outside the gridview and then row is deleted. Can I call "delete" event method inside the "edit" event, because I want to first retrieve values in controls and then row is deleted.

Here is my aspx.cs code. Both delete and edit event code here :

```
protected void GridView2_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
    t.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
    GridView2.DataSource = t;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}

public void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
    TextBox1.Text=GridView2.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString();

    DropDownList1.Text = GridView2.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
    GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
    GridView2.DataSource = t;
    GridView2.DataBind();

    //CAN I CALL GRIDVIEW_ROW_DELETING method here? I try but problem is arguments etc
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Emanuaele said, there's better ways to do this, but if you want to keep your code close to what you have, move your delete code into a separate method

```
protected void DeletingRow(int rowIndex)
{
    DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
    t.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
    GridView2.DataSource = t;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Then GridView2_RowDeleting would change to

```
protected void GridView2_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    DeletingRow(e.RowIndex);
}
```

And GridView2_RowEditing would change to

```
public void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    DaTable t = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
    TextBox1.Text=GridView2.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
    DropDownList1.Text =   GridView2.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
    GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
    GridView2.DataSource = t;
    GridView2.DataBind();
    //CAN I CALL HERE GRIDVIEW_ROW_DELETING METHOD,I try but problem is arguemnts etc

    DeletingRow(e.NewEditIndex);
}
```

Comment: @March thanks for answer,but there is one red line error come.in "Gridview2_RowEditing" error come at last line  DeletingRow(GridView2.RowIndex); //at RowIndex, because method contain GridViewEditEventArgs e pass

Comment: does not contain defination of RowIndex

Comment: Sorry should be CurrentRow.Index

Comment: I check it now,but it's not working,here is snap shot http://hostthenpost.org/uploads/2343991ab460f29ec78fea625b680e43.png

Comment: Maybe it's e.NewEditIndex
But it's not correct! It's better to use RowCommmand

Comment: You will need to look at the properties of GridView2 to see which provides the index of the selected row. Might be SelectedRow.RowIndex. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Let me check SelectedRow.RowIndex.

Comment: here is output http://hostthenpost.org/uploads/f972ef385ec5446d2aa8db7b24669294.png

Comment: Ouhh great man..Thanks it working now.DeletingRow(e.NewEditIndex); working fine :) Thank You,Kindly update your answer with this command.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Approach is wrong if data comes from a database. 
You have to work on data, not on controls of page (you can but it's better not to do).

Don't use Session to store Datatable (how many records are there in?)

Use `CommandArgument` of your button to get the Id of the record.
Retrieve record from database and store fields in controls. Click a button, save data, delete the record and rebind.

Using your approach, you can move the code of deleting event in a private method and call it from editing event

Comment: I don't want any database connectivity right now..Actaully my idea is first user insert values into gridview and then press button "Create table" then all values inserted into the database..First tell me pelase,can i call delete event method in edit event?

Comment: Read Marc's answer